# Android Device Monitor not deleting files

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

Whenever I click the `Delete the selection` button in my Android Device Monitor, nothing happens. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Maybe missing to stop the app before del?

Comment: The app isn't running and I'm still getting the problem

Comment: Go to Android Studio's AVD Manager and wipe data from your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

try this
Tools->Android->Enabled ABD Integration and make disable it.
then: Tool->Android->Android Device Monitor and try again

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my Android Device Monitor, the problem was solved